# Beautiful Soup adding quotations of HTML attributes

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Thanks in advance,

I'm currently using beautiful soup to parse comment tags out of a set block of HTML. The issue I'm having is the html that is scraped has no quotations encapsulating the attribute values of the HTML tags. However BeautifulSoup seems to add these in, which in some case may be desirable but unfortunately not for my case.

Which would be the best route to either leave the actually HTML intact without adding the quotes in via BeautifulSoup - or can these be added back in?

Comment: Please add some code and HTML so we can help you.

Comment: BeautifulSoup is a parser that just reads your HTML and optionally prints it out again.  It does not "add" quotation marks.  If you don't want them, don't use BeautifulSoup's printing capabilities, but traverse the tree and produce the output by yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a tag where some attribute values are quoted and some unquoted. What do you mean  by 'add quoting back': either [edit each attribute value](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Changing%20attribute%20values) to kludge the quotes in (probably a terrible idea), or else add quoting when it renders. It depends on what other processing you're doing to the tag. Here's code to add quotes when it prints:

```
input = "<html><sometag attr1=dont_quote_me attr2='but this one is quoted'>Text</sometag></html>"

bs = BeautifulSoup(input)

bs2 = bs.find('sometag')
for a in bs2.attrs:
    (attr,aval) = a
    print "%s='%s'" % (attr,aval),
```

gives `attr1='dont_quote_me' attr2='but this one is quoted'`

It's up to you which way. I assume they're all single-words i.e. match regex `\w+`